# Cómo puedo aumentar la velocidad del Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Busco aumentar la velocidad del Scroll para bajar y subir usando la rueda de manera mas rápida, otra sería también al bajar la barra con el click del ratón y desplazarlo.

Éste es mi código:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {

    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable = true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis = "yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default

    $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "rounded-dots"
    });

    $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
        rel = $this.attr("rel"),
        el = $(".content");
      switch (rel) {
        case "toggle-content":
          el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
          break;
      }
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 480px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: "Lobster Two", "Georgia", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #6bdaea;
}

hr {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 740px;
  max-width: 97%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content hr {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.content p {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content p:nth-child(odd),
.content.light p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.content p:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: #bbb;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.content h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.content:nth-child(odd) h2 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1229px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 1060px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1629px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Scrollbar con Jquery</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h6j1ynikq69ecoz/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollbar2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Scroball con jquery afectando el body</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 2</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 3</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 4</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Fin del contenido.</p>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbxdnhkqpdomxxv/jquery.scrollController.js"></script>
  <script src="scrollbarr2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación del plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-scrollInertia) que estás usando se indica un parámetro para controlar la duración de la animación del scroll (y por lo tanto su velocidad). El parámetro es `scrollInertia` (traducción mía):

> `scrollInertia`: integer
>   Determina la cantidad de inercia del scroll como la duración de la aniamación en milisegundos.
>   Un valor más alto indica una mayor inercia de scroll lo que se traduce en una animación más suave y más progresiva. Si se pone el valor a cero, se desactiva.

El valor por defecto para `scrollInertia` es 950 (lo puedes ver en el [código del plugin](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js#L118)), por lo que cualquier valor menor que ese  hará que el scroll se mueva más rápido (pero de manera más brusca) y un valor mayor hará que se mueva más lento (y suave).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo en el que he cambiado el valor a 500 para que el scroll vaya más rápido de lo normal:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {

    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable = true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis = "yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default

    $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "rounded-dots",
      scrollInertia: 500
    });

    $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
        rel = $this.attr("rel"),
        el = $(".content");
      switch (rel) {
        case "toggle-content":
          el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
          break;
      }
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 480px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: "Lobster Two", "Georgia", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #6bdaea;
}

hr {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 740px;
  max-width: 97%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content hr {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.content p {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content p:nth-child(odd),
.content.light p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.content p:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: #bbb;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.content h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.content:nth-child(odd) h2 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1229px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 1060px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1629px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Scrollbar con Jquery</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h6j1ynikq69ecoz/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollbar2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Scroball con jquery afectando el body</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 2</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 3</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />

  <h2>Scroball con jquery 4</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Fin del contenido.</p>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbxdnhkqpdomxxv/jquery.scrollController.js"></script>
  <script src="scrollbarr2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```